# PHP - MySQL IF (boolean) condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, normalization

Sorry I wasn't sure how to title this question but I'll do my best to explain my problem. I have two tables in my DB that look like this:

```
APPLICATIONS:

app_id | data1 | data2
----------------------

1      | foo   | foo
2      | bar   | bar




APP_REQUIREMENTS:

app_id | requirement  | is_satisfied
--------------------------------------
1      | requirement1 | false
1      | requirement2 | false
2      | requirement1 | true
2      | requirement2 | true
```

What I am trying to do is query my DB to get all information from the APPLICATIONS table along with an extra field that represents whether there are any UNSATISFIED requirements for that application so my query would return something like this:

```
app_id | data1 | data2 | meets_all_requirements
------------------------------------------------
1      | foo   | foo   | false
2      | bar   | bar   | true
```

What would be the best way to do this with one query? Is there a better way to set up my tables/relationships to accommodate this?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `is_satisfied` is a boolean field, then `min()` effective does an `and` on all the conditions:

```
select a.*, min(is_satisfied) as all_satisfied
from Application a left outer join
     App_Requirements ar
     on a.app_id = ar.app_id
group by a.app_id;
```

If the values are really strings, you can do:

```
select a.*, min(is_satisfied = 'true') as all_satisfied
from Application a left outer join
     App_Requirements ar
     on a.app_id = ar.app_id
group by a.app_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for. in your opinion is this the best way to handle this type of 1:N relationship?

Comment: @A.O.  This seems to be a reasonable structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*, sum(not r.is_satisfied) = 0 as meets_all_requirements
from applications a
left join app_requirements r on a.app_id = r.app_id
group by a.app_id
```